Cómo cambiar Base de Datos (DataContext) en una API en C#(.NET) en tiempo de ejecución?
Tengo un API con su DataContext y su correspondiente ConnectionString a una BD en donde tengo los Usuarios para el Login.
Hasta ahí todo bien.
Ahora....tengo un Usuario1 de la EmpresaA, y un Usuario2 de la EmpresaB.
Cada empresa tiene su BD. Las dos son iguales, las mismas tablas, las mismas estructuras.
Entonces tengo que definir otros ConnectionString .....ConnectionStringA y ConnectionStringB.
Y los correspondientes  DataContext..... DataContextA y DataContextB (y ponerlos en el program.cs obviamente).
Ahora la duda.... cómo puedo hacer para que en un Controller por ejemplo ProductsController....vaya a una BD u a otra según el usuario que esté logueado?
Para que el UsuarioA vea los Productos de la BD A, y el UsuarioB vea los Productos de la BD B?
Es decir como puedo cambiar de DataContext en los Controllers en tiempo de ejecución según sea el Usuario que está haciendo la petición?
Hay forma de hacerlo? Alguien me puede orientar? algo para leer?
He buscado muchísimo en Internet y no encuentro nada que me pueda indicar qué camino seguir....
Muchas pero muchísimas gracias!!!
Abrazo de Córdoba Argentina!!

Las dos bases de datos tienen exactamente la misma estructura?
Te conectas a la base de datos por Entity Framework?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Las dos BD son iguales (lo dice mi pregunta original). Y si...con Entity Framework. En cuanto a ser mas claro...sin ánimo de ofender a nadie creo que fui suficientemente claro....Quiero que si un UsuarioA se loguea, cunado use el ProductsController pueda ver los Productos de la BD A que usa el stringConnectionA / DataContextA... mientras que si es un UsuarioB el que se loguea (de otra empresa) vea los productos de la BD B que usa el stringConnectionB / DataContextB....no sé como hacer eso....si es que se puede....no encuentro nada...ningún camino que me oriente en esa direccion. Gracias

Estimado Luis.
Si te he entendido bien has separado los datos en dos BD diferentes una para cada cliente.
Creo que puede ser de ayuda para ti este artículo del cual te paso el link.
https://dev.to/isaacojeda/asp-net-core-6-creando-una-app-multi-tenant-parte-1-3df5

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.

es mucho código, pero, en teoría el esquema de MultiTennant puede funcionar para lo que el quiere.
